# Является ли расширение файла его trailing suffix

Tags: linux, windows

Является ли расширение файла его trailing suffix (по терминологии linux)?
В частности, что является расширением файла и trailing suffix в имени `.foo` .

---

**Наблюдения**

Команда [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) (linux):
`basename -s .foo .foo`
выводит `.foo` (считает, что в данном случае нет trailing suffix).

В [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/extension) такая строка:
`std::cout << std::experimental::filesystem::path(".foo").extension() << '\n'`
выводит `.foo` (считает, что расширение есть).

В [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_) это:
`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(".foo")`
дает пустую строку (считает, что расширение есть).

Также, как указал [Andrey NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45088014#45088014) проводник (Windows) отображает файл ".mp3" именно с иконкой mp3-файла.

Comment: Нет, не является. Расширение файла есть под WIN. В обычных ОС есть trailing suffix - любые, допустимые в имени файла, символы начиная со второго символа имени файла. `basename -s foo .foo` выведет `.` (точку).

Comment: Ваши примеры не равноценны. *basename* знает о специальной трактовке файлов, начинающихся с точки. А по сути в нормальных ОС такого понятия-то нет — тип файла определяется через mime type.

Answer (score 1):

технически [расширение **имени** файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) (именно имени, а не самого файла) существовало в допотопных версиях файловой системы [*fat*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT) (и ещё в [нескольких ф.с.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)). нет, оно, конечно, никуда не делось, но с появлением *vfat* стало неактуальным.

под имя файла [в *fat* отводилось 11 байт](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Directory_entry), первые восемь из которых трактовались как «имя», а последние три — как «расширение» ([первоначально было вообще 6+3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT12)).

эти две группы байтов обычно разделялись при отображении для пользователя точкой, которая не могла входить в имя файла.

с тех пор это ограничение снято (а для подавляющего большинства файловых систем вообще никогда не существовало).

то есть, «расширение имени файла» — нынче скорее оторванное от реальности понятие, без однозначного технического смысла. **потому кто как хочет, тот так его и трактует** (это, собственно, ответ на заданный вопрос).

---

немного точнее отображающим нынешнюю картину является термин «суффикс имени файла».